# Get Next and Previous 5 Posts from the Current Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I read out the wordpress codex for show the previous post and next post it working fine. But how can i show that previous 5 post title with hyperlink and next 5 post title with hyperlink when i view it from the current post.
For example:

**Post 1, Post 2, Post 3, Post 4, Post 5**

When i view the ** Post 3** then it show the previous post as **Post 1 and Post 2**  and Next post show **Post 4 and Post 5**

How can i do this?

Comment: Check this Out....... it might help you .

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14502/get-next-prev-3-posts-in-relation-to-current-post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get by following

```
<?php   global $post;
 $current_post = $post; // remember the current post

      for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++):
        $post = get_previous_post(); // this uses $post->ID
      setup_postdata($post);

          // do your stuff here       
     the_title();
    the_content();

       endfor;
        $post = $current_post; 

        ?>
```

also for newt 5 post use `get_next_post()` instead of `get_previous_post()`

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can i make that corresponding title to link. I mean Hyperlink to particular post

Comment: Thanks finally i did by own to give the hyperlink by <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>